# Changing variables in a Latex file using Matlab

Tags: pdftex, mac, matlab

I'm trying to import an excel sheet to Matlab, then I use the data to change variables using Matlab then I generate a new tex file as below (found the code online).Everythig is working except for the last step I'm getting the following error in Matlab
cmdout =
'zsh:1: command not found: pdflatex
'
I checked online, the advice to install Mactex, but I do have it and when I check the terminal, it does recognize pdflatex, so what is the problem in that case, I would appreciate the advise.

```
A=ENCS300S2;
[row,col]=size(A);
A2=A.Variables;

text = fileread('CLO2.tex');
newtext = strrep(text,'TPone',num2str(A2(row,2)));       
fileID = fopen('newMWEE.tex','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%s',newtext);
fclose(fileID);
command = 'pdflatex newMWEE.tex';
[status,cmdout] = system(command)
```

Updated: I added the command `setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ':~/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex']);` it did not work. I got the path to pdflatex by going to the terminal and using which pdflatex

**Update:** I did not find anything that can help online. so I decided to look into other tools such as Python, did anyone try that before and worked for him ?

Comment: this is probably a problem of PATH setting best asked on some Matlab forum. BTW, you have *lots* of questions with answers where you did not accept any... ;-)

Comment: The sintaxe I used when I rarely compite .tex from matlab is:  `dos(sprintf('pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %s.tex && exit &', filename));`, where `filename` is a given parameter.

Comment: @Rmano I do usually dear accept the correct answers, if any fixed my problem. I use Mac.

Comment: @Diana, are you trying to save a `.tex` file with data from Matlab through Matlab or are you trying to compile a `.tex` file from within Matlab? I have a library named [Matlab to LaTeX](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72155-matlab-to-latex-library), mainly, I create `.tex` files from Matlab, but I don't actually advice compiling them, from my personal experience and tests, it is normally slower. The library I create to handle files is [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71864-file-manipulation-library).I combine both to properly create my files.

Comment: I'm trying to get some information from an excel sheet, then update a .tex file (like a template) using the information from the excel sheet, then I want to generate a pdf with the updated files automatically in one Matlab loop. The document is only a cover page.

Comment: @FHz do you have a Youtube video describing your functions? I couldn't run your files

Comment: @Diana, if you still have some difficult, we may continue the explanation in a chat.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction and Preparation

This answers provides an integrated method to generate a `.tex` file from `matlab` and also compile the main file from `matlab` using Windows. I will be using my libraries [Matlab to LaTeX](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72155-matlab-to-latex-library) and [File Manipulation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/71864-file-manipulation-library). Don't worry, I'll explain what each function does.

This is our `MWE.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\input{input_test}
\end{document}
```

where `input_test` will be the file created from `matlab`.

As your are working with Excel files, I will create this example using the following matrix: `A = [4 5; 1 2; 10 90]`.

This is our `test.m` file:

```
%% Data set
A = [4 5; 1 2; 10 90];
var = 'A'; f = '%g'; option = 2;
s = fc_lib_latex_matrix_num(var,A,f,option);
string_to_file = fc_lib_latex_block_equation(s);
%% Always create files correctly
str_ext = '.tex'; file_name = 'input_test'; encod = 'UTF-8';
fc_lib_file_save_file_extensao(file_name, str_ext, string_to_file, encod);
%% Error with more than one line
fid = fopen('input_option.tex','w');
fprintf(fid, '%s', string_to_file);
fclose(fid);
%% Compile
filename = 'MWE';
fc_lib_latex_compile_from_matlab(filename);
```

#### *Edit* -- Add to Path

The final preparation step is to edit the `path` where `matlab` searches for functions. All my functions need to be added to the Path (*Set Path*). The functions work as a library, the may be called from any folder.

[image]

[image]

#### Data set

The basic concept of all automatic file creation is to prepare a string variable to be written. That said, `A` is not a string, we need to create the sintax in LaTeX to write this matrix, here comes `fc_lib_latex_matrix_num` resulting in:

```
s =

  6×15 char array

    'A =            '
    '\begin{bmatrix}'
    '   4 &     5 \\     '
    '   1 &     2 \\     '
    '   10 &    90      '
    '\end{bmatrix}  '
```

now, as I want to not write repeated syntax, let's add `\begin{equation}` to it with `fc_lib_latex_block_equation`:

```
string_to_file =

  8×16 char array

    '\begin{equation}'
    'A =             '
    '\begin{bmatrix} '
    '   4 &     5 \\      '
    '   1 &     2 \\      '
    '   10 &    90       '
    '\end{bmatrix}   '
    '\end{equation}  '
```

perfect, our string is done and ready to become a `.tex` file.

#### Always create files correctly

Now we need to understand how `fprintf` really works.

As I've written these functions long time ago, I use `fc_lib_file_save_file_extensao` to encapsulate all info I need to create a file correctly regarding to input codification, i.e., `UTF-8`, `ISO-859-1`, etc.
This function calls `fc_lib_file_save_file_tex`, this one is the trick to avoid `fprintf` error. It writes the given string line per line and removes white spaces at the right. The result will be the file `input_test.tex`. As I've written the code, the file is **always** overwritten.

#### Error with more than one line

Now focusing on the issue with. If you create a string with more than one line, you will probably generate a file with incorrect information, for example, this is the result for `input_option.tex` when I write the same string as before.

`\A\            \\b b001eee=e410nng g   ddi i&&&{{n n   be{ { ...`

#### Compile

At this point, you should be able to compile our `MWE.tex` from your editor or from the command prompt with `pdflatex MWE.tex` from the folder where the file is. This is the test you must do and your system must pass. If it doesn't work, I have no idea how matlab could compile LaTeX.

My function `fc_lib_latex_compile_from_matlab` just prepares data and stores syntax to compile a `.tex` from matlab. The core syntax is: `dos(sprintf('pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %s.tex && exit &', filename))`, where `filename` is the given string input. The part `&& exit &` is inserted to close the prompt screen afterwards. The compact form `pdflatex MWE.tex` is the only part strictly necessary.

The core syntax is the one you should check how to use in your operation system (Mac).

### Result

The result is the same `pdf` as you should have when compiling through the command prompt or your editor. Just remember compiling enough times to all tools work properly.

[image]

#### A brief video of the results

I prepared the files, run the `test.m` file. You may see all files created, including the pdf, which is presented at the end.

[image]